# Exact category and surjection

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be an epi morphism in an exact category and $g:X\rightarrow B$ be a morphism.

Is there a morphism $h:X\rightarrow A$ such that $g=f\circ  h$?

Comment: In general no. For example, in the category of abelian groups, let $A=\mathbb Z/4$, $B=X=\mathbb Z/2$, $g$ the identity map, and $f$ the homomorphism sending $1$ and $3$ to $1$ and sending $0$ and $2$ to $0$.

Comment: An object $X$ is called *projective* if the conclusion you asked about is true for all $f,A,B,g$.  In the category of abelian groups, the projective objects are exactly the free abelian groups.

Comment: Although the linked question is not exactly a duplicate, my answer there shows that what you ask is not true. I give a counterexample in the category of groups, which is exact (as is any variety in the sense of universal algebra). Note also that the category of rings is exact, but the injection $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism that certainly cannot have this property!